# C++11 standard document costs

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Why are there different PDF versions of the ISO/IEC 14882:2011 standard (C++11), which cost from $30 to $761? (see http://webstore.ansi.org or any other distributor)

btw.: Has the INCITS $30 version just been published? It's available at the ANSI web store, but not at the INCITS web store..

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12276683/420683

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just the way the standards organizations work. They're not competing with each other to get your business.

You can basically get the C++11 standard for free anyway. See n3337 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/#mailing2012-01). It's the standard plus the first few post-standardization corrections of typos and the like.

Comment: [Direct link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).