# Buying the C++11 Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) from an Authorized Body

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

I am contemplating on getting ISO/IEC 14882:2011 from an Authorized body in a legal way, not by downloading any pirated copy.

I am confused by the fact that at ansi.org they charge only $30.00 whereas iso.org charges 238 Swiss Frank (=$240)!

Since both ISO and ANSI are authorized bodies, should I ignore the pricing discrepancy? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Just [get a draft source](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft), it is perfectly legal (although if you need an actual ISO draft that is a different story). Also, you question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the price difference, you should buy it where it's cheapest, unless you like throwing money away. :)

Comment: Nobody owns the C++ standard. ISO pricing policy makes sure of that.

Comment: Just get the N3337 draft. It's just like the standard with some editorial fixes.

Comment: How in the world can the obtaining of a programming language standard be "off topic" in a programmer forum?!

Comment: @sellibitze N3376 is even more up to date.

Comment: @FredOverflow: N3337 is even closer to the standard. ;)

Comment: @sbi FWIW, if the question were merely "where can I buy the C++11 standard", I would not have voted to close. This question is closer to "why does ISO charge so much for the C++11 standard", which doesn't really have anything to do with programming.

Comment: @hvd: Read again. He writes "I am confused...", not "Isn't that outrageous?!"

Comment: @sbi I didn't read it as "Isn't that outrageous?!", I do read it as a legitimate question. I still think this is the wrong place for it. But if others vote to reopen, who am I to disagree?

Comment: @user - ISO is charging the same price for the standard as a hardcopy book and as a .pdf file. They just haven't figured that out yet. ANSI has noted that there *is* a huge difference.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9771868/420683

Comment: Another way for you: find lastest standard (also compoud beta-version) and free: https://isocpp.org . We don't need buy offical documents from ISO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore the pricing discrepancy. Both are official sources.

Answer (score 14):

You can get [the current draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) for free, legally. It is even more up to date than the published standard :)

Comment: It also includes stuff that isn't part of C++11. It's *too* "up to date".

Answer (score 1):

While not the C++11 standard, but based on it, the [Standard C++ Foundation](http://isocpp.org/) website features a link to its [working draft of the next standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/master/papers) on GitHub.

Comment: That's rather off-topic. The topic being the C++11 standard, which is *not that*.

Comment: @Nicol: True, the GitHub repository does not include version ISO/IEC 14882; however, since the standard only changes so fast, the PDFs there are close, and since they are also authoritative, I thought worth mentioning. Additionally, it's common on SO to answer version-specific questions with information about a later versions (c.f. [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129079/167867)). GitHub holds the official work on the next release.

Comment: Maybe, but at the very least you should say *which* is closer to C++11. More importantly, the question is not about *where to find the standard*; it's about the *price* of the standard from different sources. So again, it's off topic.